# How to retrieve date from a timestamp - sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get a count of all the rows with the current date.

```
Column name = LOGIN_TIME (format is TIMESTAMP)
```

Now I have `USER_NAME` and `SUBJECT` values.

Table structure:

```
USER_NAME   SUBJECT   LOGIN_TIME
-----------------------------------
abc         physics   01-MAY-13 12.27.50.863000000 AM
abc         math      02-MAY-13 01.01.47.863000000 PM
def         physics   16-MAY-13 06.42.48.863000000 PM    
abc         physics   16-MAY-13 02.29.11.863000000 PM
```

Now, with `user_name='aaa'` and `subject = 'physics'`, and `current date (of REQUEST_TIME)`, I want to retreive the count of rows.

Please help me with this query.

Comment: *correction: USER_NAME= 'abc' and subject = 'physics'

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged the question with SQL Developer I assume you are using Oracle.

In that case you can use the `trunc()` function to "remove" the time part of a timestamp (or `date`) column. "remove" means that it's set to 00:00:00. You also need to do this for `current_date`, `sysdate` or `current_timestamp` as all of them (including `current_date`) carry the time with them

Having said that, the result would be something like this:

```
select count(*) 
from the_table 
where user_name = 'abc' 
  and subject = 'physics' 
  and trunc(login_time) = trunc(current_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the work. just replace `Table_name` with your table's actual name.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Table_Name WHERE USER_NAME = 'abc' AND SUBJECT = 'physics' AND TRUNC(LOGIN_TIME) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am getting an error when i run this script in oracle sql developer:
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT Count(*) FROM table_name WHERE user_name = 'abc' AND subject= 'physics' AND login_time (timestamp) = Date(now())
Error at Command Line:2 Column:51
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: did you change the Table_name ?

Comment: @user2388729: The answer is not valid for Oracle and was posted before it was clear that you are using Oracle - **which you should have stated right from the beginning**. `now()` seems to indicate it was intended for SQL Server or MySQL. But the expression `LOGIN_TIME (timestamp)` is not valid in any database if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: the question says **-sql** thats why i thought of SQL server.. it could've worked if user had removed (timestamp)

Comment: Yes i did change the table_name. I guess it was the type conversion that didn't work. Trunc worked its charm thou.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. should have mentioned that earlier. 
But it dint work with the removal of (timestamp) either.

Comment: @AhmedZ.: the tag `SQL` refers the **query language**. SQL it not a "product". Questions for the Microsoft product are (should be) tagged with `sql-server`